# understand the running trace of quicksort in prolog

Tags: sorting, prolog, quicksort, trace

I have the following prolog code for quicksort:

```
gt(X,Y):- X @> Y.
conc([], List, List).
conc([Head|Tail], List1, [Head|List2]):- conc(Tail, List1, List2).

quicksort([], []).
quicksort([X|Tail], Sorted):-
    split(X,Tail,Small,Big),
    quicksort(Small,SortedSmall),
    quicksort(Big, SortedBig),
    conc(SortedSmall, [X|SortedBig], Sorted).

split(X,[],[],[]).
split(X,[Y|Tail],[Y|Small],Big):-
    gt(X,Y),
    !,
    split(X,Tail,Small, Big).

split(X,[Y|Tail],Small,[Y|Big]):-
    split(X,Tail,Small,Big).
```

The array for example is [3,2,4,1,5]. quicksort([3,2,4,1,5], Sorted). I need to understand the running trace of the program. I almost do but there is one point that I don't: (this is just a part of the trace):

```
Redo: (11) split(3, [5], _G3785, _G3782) ? creep
Call: (12) split(3, [], _G3785, _G3788) ? creep
Exit: (12) split(3, [], [], []) ? creep
Exit: (11) split(3, [5], [], [5]) ? creep
Exit: (10) split(3, [1, 5], [1], [5]) ? creep
Exit: (9) split(3, [4, 1, 5], [1], [4, 5]) ? creep
Exit: (8) split(3, [2, 4, 1, 5], [2, 1], [4, 5]) ? creep
```

Why do we have Exit: (11) split(3, [5], [], [5]) ? creep at the line 11, where does 5 come from?
Someone could help me please!! I'd really appreciate that.

Comment: To be clear, `(11)` is **not** a reference to a line number but the level or depth of the goal. When a subgoal is called, the level is increased by one. After the subgoal succeeds and control is returned to the caller the level is decreased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a cut after comparing at the rule number 2 of function split:

```
split(X,[Y|Tail],[Y|Small],Big):-
gt(X,Y), 
!,
split(X,Tail,Small, Big).
```

Answer (score 2):

We'll use this for reference:

```
[1] split(X,[],[],[]).
[2] split(X,[Y|Tail],[Y|Small],Big):-
        gt(X,Y),
        split(X,Tail,Small, Big).

[3] split(X,[Y|Tail],Small,[Y|Big]):-
        split(X,Tail,Small,Big).
```

And we'll follow your trace fragment.

```
Redo: (11) split(3, [5], _G3785, _G3782) ? creep
```

This redo is due to the failure of clause [2] in the original query (not shown, prior in the trace) since `gt(3,5)` is false. Redo would then result in the query of clause [3]. We'll substitute the known instantiated variables and see what that 3rd clause query looks like:

```
[A] split(3, [5|[]], Small, [5|Big]) :- split(3, [], Small, Big)
```

This leads to the next trace line, where `_G3785` is `Small`, and `_G3788` is `Big`:

```
Call: (12) split(3, [], _G3785, _G3788) ? creep
```

This will succeed on the first clause [1] and yield this part of the trace:

```
Exit: (12) split(3, [], [], []) ? creep
```

Since this was in the midst of executing clause [3] above (as shown with [A]), it yields the following since now `Small` has been instantiated with `[]` and `Big` with `[]`.

```
split(3, [5|[]], [], [5|[]])
```

In other words, execution of the third clause shown in [A] results in:

```
split(3, [5], [], [5])
```

Which is what your next trace line shows:

```
Exit: (11) split(3, [5], [], [5]) ? creep
```

Comment: actually, there is a cut (!) after the rule 1 of the split function. As what you said: if gt(3,5) which is false, prolog will backtrack and apply rule 3 of the split function. Is that right? What if gt return true? Can you explain for me?

Comment: @ThơHoàng it appears you added the cut after I answered, but it does not affect my explanation in the given example. If `gt` succeeds instead of fails, then the second clause will not backtrack, and the trace will change accordingly. If you have a new trace example where `gt` succeeds, and you need some assistance in understanding that new trace, feel free to post it as a new question.

Comment: the cut was always there, my mistake forget to put it in there. And the trace I showed was the trace with the cut. But OK, I'll try to ask a new question 'cause I'm still confused about the trace. And hopefully you may take a look and give some helps again. Many thanks!

Comment: @ThơHoàng, OK. As I said, my explanation above is independent of the cut since `gt` failed in the scenario you mentioned. Is there some part of my answer that is still unclear that I can explain better in this specific case?

Comment: No, your answer helps a lots. I misunderstand the trace(I draw it myself) from the beginning, then look at the trace of prolog which is hard to figure out. If you have time, you could help me with this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26679486/trace-route-of-the-quicksort-algorithm-prolog)  .Really appreciate your help @lurker