# trace route of the quicksort algorithm - prolog

Tags: prolog, stack-trace, quicksort

I have that previous question about this quicksort [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26648556/understand-the-running-trace-of-quicksort-in-prolog?answertab=oldest#tab-top).The prolog code for quicksort:

```
gt(X,Y):- X @>Y.
conc([],List, List).
conc([Head|Tail], List1, [Head|List2]):- conc(Tail, List1, List2).

quicksort([],[]).
quicksort([X|Tail],Sorted):-
    split(X,Tail,Small,Big),
    quicksort(Small,SortedSmall),
    quicksort(Big,SortedBig),
    conc(SortedSmall,[X|SortedBig],Sorted).

[1]split(X,[],[],[]).
[2]split(X,[Y|Tail],[Y|Small],Big):-
    gt(X,Y),!,
    split(X,Tail,Small,Big).
[3]split(X,[Y|Tail],Small,[Y|Big]):-
    split(X,Tail,Small,Big).
```

The array for example is [3,2,4,1,5]. This is the first part of the trace route:

```
?- trace, quicksort([3,2,4,1,5], Sorted).
1  Call: (7) quicksort([3, 2, 4, 1, 5], _G4136) ? creep
2  Call: (8) split(3, [2, 4, 1, 5], _G4269, _G4270) ? creep
3  Call: (9) gt(3, 2) ? creep
4  Call: (10) 3@>2 ? creep
5  Exit: (10) 3@>2 ? creep
6  Exit: (9) gt(3, 2) ? creep
7  Call: (9) split(3, [4, 1, 5], _G4261, _G4273) ? creep
8  Call: (10) gt(3, 4) ? creep
9  Call: (11) 3@>4 ? creep
10 Fail: (11) 3@>4 ? creep
11 Fail: (10) gt(3, 4) ? creep
12 Redo: (9) split(3, [4, 1, 5], _G4261, _G4273) ? creep
13 Call: (10) split(3, [1, 5], _G4261, _G4264) ? creep
```

At the line 2, prolog apply the rule [2] of split and we have `Call: (8) split(3, [2, 4, 1, 5], _G4269, _G4270)` and we have `_G4269` is `[2|Small]` and `_G4270` is `Big`.

It then compare 3 and 2, `gt(3,2)` return true and it does not execute the cut. Continue with `split(X,Tail,Small,Big)` which is `Call: (9) split(3, [4, 1, 5], _G4261, _G4273)`

If the `gt(X,Y)` return false, prolog will execute the cut and then apply the rule [3] of the split (line 11-12).

Am I doing right and why the last variable has become a new one (`_G4237` instead of `_G4270`)? Because in the code I thought it is the same.

Anyone could help me clear things out? 
Many thanks!

Comment: Each call to the predicat has its own variable. Your trace shows `_G4270` at (8) levels deep, and `_G4273` at (9) levels deep. So they are different.

Comment: you can trust variables names,specially when are generated by an algorithm !

Answer (score 0):

To be precise: your question concerns this part of the trace:

```
2  Call: (8) split(3, [2, 4, 1, 5], _G4269, _G4270) ? creep
3  Call: (9) gt(3, 2) ? creep
4  Call: (10) 3@>2 ? creep
5  Exit: (10) 3@>2 ? creep
6  Exit: (9) gt(3, 2) ? creep
7  Call: (9) split(3, [4, 1, 5], _G4261, _G4273) ? creep
```

which corresponds to the call to:

```
split(X,[Y|Tail],[Y|Small],Big):-
    gt(X,Y),!,
    split(X,Tail,Small,Big).
```

and you are right there is no *VISIBLE* reason to obtain different variables since the same variable `Big` is used. I admit it is confusing. And, you could obtain the same variable. This can be shown calling directly `split(3, [2, 4, 1, 5], S, B)` the trace is then (with swi v6.6.6):

```
[trace]  ?- split(3, [2, 4, 1, 5], S, B).
   Call: (6) split(3, [2, 4, 1, 5], _G4537, _G4538) ? creep
   Call: (7) gt(3, 2) ? creep
   Call: (8) 3@>2 ? creep
   Exit: (8) 3@>2 ? creep
   Exit: (7) gt(3, 2) ? creep
   Call: (7) split(3, [4, 1, 5], _G4630, _G4538) ? creep
```

And the same variable is used (`_G4538`).

However, the interpreter can have *INVISIBLE* reason to unify a variable `X` with a brand new one `Y` and use `Y`instead of `X` in subsequent computations. It is what occurs in your example. You can use the command `g` (goals) when debugging to obtain a backtrace, which will show the current stack trace with current variable bindings. Returning to your example, when you reach

```
7  Call: (9) split(3, [4, 1, 5], _G4261, _G4273) ?
```

type `g` to have a backtrace and you obtain something like:

```
  [9] split(3, [4, 1, 5], _G4261, _G4273)
  [8] split(3, [2, 4, 1, 5], [2|_G4261], _G4273)
  [7] quicksort([3, 2, 4, 1, 5], _G4136)
   Call: (9) split(3, [4, 1, 5], _G4261, _G4273) ?
```

And now you can see that `_G4273` is the same variable in depth [8] and [9].